MockConsumerFactory/MockProducerFactory with KafkaTemplate/KafkaListener
I'm trying to use the MockConsumerFactory and MockProducerFactory available since Spring Kafka 3.0.7 with a KafkaTemplate and KafkaListener but the listener does not pick up any records.
As a minimal replication of the issue, I took the MockConsumerTests from the Spring Kafka project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/3.0.x/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/MockConsumerTests.java, and modified it to use a KafkaTemplate. However the test fails and the debugging System.out.println statement never shown. The records sent from the KafkaTemplate are not picked up by the KafkaListener. Why is this happening?
@SpringJUnitConfig
@DirtiesContext
public class MockConsumerTests {

    @Autowired
    private Config config;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testWithMockConsumer() throws Exception {
        kafkaTemplate.send("foo", "bar");
        kafkaTemplate.send("foo", "baz");
        kafkaTemplate.send("foo", "buz");

        assertThat(this.config.deliveryLatch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();
        assertThat(this.config.count).isEqualTo(3);
        assertThat(this.config.contents).containsExactlyInAnyOrder("bar", "baz", "buz");
    }

    @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
    @EnableKafka
    public static class Config {

        final List<String> contents = new ArrayList<>();

        final CountDownLatch deliveryLatch = new CountDownLatch(3);

        volatile int count;

        @KafkaListener(topics = "foo", groupId = "grp")
        public void foo(String in) {
            System.out.println("*** IN LISTENER ***");
            this.contents.add(in);
            this.count++;
            this.deliveryLatch.countDown();
        }

        @Bean
        public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
            MockConsumer<String, String> consumer = new MockConsumer<>(OffsetResetStrategy.EARLIEST);
            TopicPartition topicPartition0 = new TopicPartition("foo", 0);
            List<TopicPartition> topicPartitions = Arrays
                    .asList(topicPartition0);
            Map<TopicPartition, Long> beginningOffsets = topicPartitions.stream().collect(Collectors
                    .toMap(Function.identity(), tp -> 0L));
            consumer.updateBeginningOffsets(beginningOffsets);
            return new MockConsumerFactory<>(() -> consumer);
        }

        @Bean
        public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory) {
            return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
        }

        @Bean
        public ProducerFactory<String, String> mockProducerFactory() {
            return new MockProducerFactory<>(() ->
                    new MockProducer<>(true, new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer()));
        }

        @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        @Bean
        public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory consumerFactory) {
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
            factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
            factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleBetweenPolls(100);
            return factory;
        }

    }

}

